# Discord.py Sending an embed on the 15th every month

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I'm trying to make a `@commands.Cog.listener()` or `@client.event` which sends an embed every month (Like the 15th on every month)

So far I just set up a task loop but I don't know how I could use datetime in the loop.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import discord

class TasksCMD(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.index = 0
        self.bot = bot
        self.printer.start()

    #something here to wait for the 15th of every month and send one embed on that day


def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(TasksCMD(bot))
```

Any tips would be greatly help!

Comment: use `import datetime` module to check the calendar and use a simple if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def check_time(ctx)
    date = datetime.now()
    if date.day == 15:
        await ctx.send(embed=your_embed)


@bot.command()
async def start_loop(ctx):
    check_time.start(ctx)
    await ctx.send('Started loop')
```

if you want to start the loop `on_ready`

```py
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def check_time(channel)
    date = datetime.now()
    if date.day == 15:
        await channel.send(embed=your_embed)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

    channel = bot.get_channel(some_channel_id_here)
    check_time.start(channel)
```